# function or class from url

Tags: django, django-urls

I use django as a backend. I have big project and there are many views(ViewSets from django-rest-framework, views and functions). And I use React as a front and and how can I get function or class which will be called from the url. For example I have the url:

api/v2/users/322/send_letters/1232/

from this url I want to know which class or function will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [**`resolve()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) that can be used for resolving URL paths to the corresponding view functions.

> Be careful when using `resolve(path)` the function raises a Resolver404 if the URL does not resolve (Doesn't exist in your all URLs patterns)

```
    >>> from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

    >>> path = 'api/v2/users/322/send_letters/1232/'
    >>> match = resolve(path) 
    >>> match.url_name
    >>> 'url_name'
    >>> match.view_name
    >>> match.func # func, that you are looking for
```

**`match.view_name`** will return the name of the view that matches the URL, including the namespace if there is one.

Comment: yes, I am looking for it. But I use django 2.0 and it is deprecated. Now resolve I can import like this: from django.urls import reverse